# Whats a good way to find a good designer?

Tags: website-design, print-design, business, marketing

I'm running a company that needs design work from time to time. Things like business cards, web design, marketing materials, etc. We probably have about 20 hours a month of design work on average.

What are good resources for finding designers? Where do designers look for clients? I've tried my network to no avail. Should I be posting on job search sites? Are there design forums that designers frequent?

Edit: The company I'm running is a start up, so while I'm willing to pay a designer, I'd rather not have to pay a headhunter to find one.

Comment: Simply hire us all! ;)

Comment: Either use a job or freelance site or contact a headhunter to have them look for you. Any "design forums" will most likely yield a bunch of "Hire Me" people that are under qualified or otherwise unacceptable. How would you hire a new receptionist? It's the same procedure.

Comment: @scott A bunch of "Hire Me"s with links to portfolios and resumes would actually be pretty helpful

Answer (score 2):

- word of mouth (Typically the most common method)
- your local Chamber of Commerce (or other business org) if you want to stay local
- your local startup incubator/organization (they should have plenty of suggestions)
- your local AIGA (in the USA. Other countries likely have their own graphic design industry groups)
- Web sites such as dribbble.com or behance.com etc. where graphic designers post their portfolios

Comment: Canada has AIGA, too.